# Defining [(ngModel)] for checkbox array to get output in different JSON format using forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to define [(ngModel)] for check boxes and convert them in some different format using forms like below:

In component file:

```
...
public roleList = [{"role":"ROLE_ADMIN","privileges":null},{"role":"ROLE_USER","privileges":null},{"role":"ROLE_READONLY","privileges":null}];
public privilegeList = [{"name":"ADMIN_READ_WRITE"},{"name":"ADMIN_READ"},{"name":"USER_READ_WRITE"},{"name":"READONLY"}];
public roleFormData = {"privileges":[{"name":null}],"role":null};

public populateRoleForm(roleForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(roleForm.value);
    this.roleFormData = roleForm.value;
}
...
```

In HTML file:

```
...
<form #roleForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="populateRoleForm(roleForm);" *ngIf="roleFormData">
    <select name="role" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.role">
        <option *ngFor="let role of roleList" value="role.role">{{role.role}}</option>
    </select>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let privilege of privilegeList; let in=index">
        <input type="checkbox" name="privilegeName" value="privilege.name" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[in].name" />{{privilege.name}}
    </ng-container>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</form>
...
```

Error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UsersComponent.html:65)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]
```

line 65 in html is: `<input type="checkbox" name="privilegeName" value="privilege.name" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[in].name" />{{privilege.name}}`

Not sure how to define [(ngModel)] for checkboxes in this case. How I can get my desired roleFormData?

**EDIT:**

I changed my HTML as:

```
<form #roleForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="populateRoleForm(roleForm);roleModal=false;" *ngIf="roleFormData">
    <select name="roleName" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.role">
        <option *ngFor="let role of roleList">{{role.role}}</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <ng-container *ngFor="let privilege of privilegeList; let i=index">
        <input type="checkbox" name="privilegeNames" value="{{privilege}}" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[i].name" />{{privilege.name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </ng-container>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="roleModal=false">CANCEL</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</form>
```

and component as:

```
public roleFormData = {"privileges":[{"name":null},{"name":null},{"name":null},{"name":null}],"role":null};
```

But the console for `roleForm.value` in `populateRoleForm` method is giving me `{roleName: "ROLE_USER", privilegeNames: true}` but I wanted to get `privilegeNames` as `[{"name":"ADMIN_READ_WRITE"},{"name":"ADMIN_READ"}]` ie. all selected values. How I can get this?

Comment: doesn't should be ```[(ngModel)]="privilege.name"``` ?

Comment: At least this resole my console error. But I am still getting wrong output format: If I am selecting some privilege '`{role: "role.role", privilegeName: false}`, and `{role: "role.role", privilegeName: "READONLY"}`. And also value of privilege is changing to false/tru after selecting and diselecting checkboxes.

Comment: what if check it with ngif : ```<input *ngIf="roleFormData.privileges[in]" type="checkbox" name="privilegeName" value="privilege.name" [(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[in].name" />```

Answer (score 0):

Your `roleFormData.privileges` don't have the same number of objects as that in the `privilegeList`. Due to that, you're getting the error as for the value of index 1 or more, you're not going to have objects in the `roleFormData.privileges` array.

To fix that, you might want to either add equal number of Objects as you have in `privilegeList` or change `[(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[in].name"` to `[(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[0].name"`, whatever suits your purpose.

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thqppf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Actually both `roleList` and `privilegeList` are coming from backend. So I can't have fixed list.

Comment: This should be something that your backend should take care of in that case. Or else just use `[(ngModel)]="roleFormData.privileges[0].name"`

Comment: Hey @SiddAjmera I updated my code in the same way you suggested in the example. But still I am not getting the roleFormData in correct format. Can you check my edit in question section?